# Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire « questo » ?

Tags: expressions, argot, salutations

### Contexte

J'étais dans un bus à Montpellier quand j'ai entendu un mec dire à une fille quelque chose qui, à mes oreilles, ressemble à *« questo »*. Je crois qu'il l'a dit comme *« Bonjour »*, peut-être comme question. En même temps, il lui a tapé dans la main, ce qui me fait penser que c'était une salutation. Cependant les joues de la jeune sont devenues rouges, et elle et sa mère riaient.

Le garçon et son copain l'ont fait quand ils sont montés dans le bus, puis ils ont continué vers la fille sans s'arrêter.

Est-ce une blague entre amis, un type d'accueil, ou quoi ?

Comment: Peut-être a-t-il dit "Kefa ?", une expression qui signifie "quoi ?"
ou alors je pense aussi à "qu'est c'ta ?", une version abrégée de "Qu'est-ce que tu as ?"

Comment: @Lulucmy moi je pense pas mais c'est toujours possible (mes oreilles s'adaptent lentement)

Comment: Je ne vois pas d'autre expression proche...
"Michto" à la limite (c'est une insulte)
Et que voulez-vous dire par  "il l'a donné cinq" ?

Comment: @Lulucmy En anglais "high five" ?

Comment: Ah d'accord :)

Mais pour "questo" je vois vraiment pas...

Comment: @Lulucmy merci en tout cas, puisque j’ai malentendu probablement

Comment: Je suis désolé @David Ben Knoble, en espérant que quelqu'un d'autre ait une idée...

Comment: Ça peut aussi ressembler à « casse-toi », mais je vois mal comment l'expliquer... Les deux garçons ont dit la même chose ? Il y a aussi un arrêt de bus qui s'appelle « Castors » à Montpellier...

Comment: Il y a un Castorama à Montpellier ? Même si le « qu'est c'tô » (with the « ô » instead of « a », like « j'sais pô », puis « qu'est c'ta » (as suggested by Lulucmy) seems plausible too.

Comment: Merci bien à tous. Vraiment je sais pas.

Comment: Tu ne sais pas si les deux garçons ont dit la même chose ? Ce n'est pas clair dans ta question. Et c'était quelle ligne de bus ?

Comment: @jlliagre non je sais pas. Je crois que le deuxième a tapé dans la main uniquement. Et bon c’était le numéro 11 aux bouisses

Comment: C'était pas la ligne 35 ( https://moovitapp.com/index/fr/transport_en_commun-line-35-Montpellier-3817-1079530-664290-2749533 ) ? Est-ce qu'ils ont dit autre chose ?
 Si oui, c'était bien en français ?

Comment: Pas le 35 et pas d’autre chose que je sâche @jlliagre. Le 35 vas au castelnez et j’allais au sud

Comment: Peut-être il prétendait en effet connaître l'italien ? Il pouvait utiliser *questo* (*this*) comme *bonjour, c'est moi* (je ne sais pas si c'est correct en italien)… Les possibilités sont trop nombreuses…

Comment: @Evgeniy En italien, ça se prononce  kouèsto. Je ne pense pas que c'est ce qu'a entendu David.

Answer (score 2):

Si le son était bien "questo" alors ça n'est pas du français. A mon avis c'est un terme né dans une des classes du lycée de ces jeunes. D'après le contexte cela pourrait être une contraction avec faute de conjugaison de "como estas ?" qui aurait donné "como esto" puis "cuesto".

Answer (score 2):

C'est de la spéculation, mais à la description qui en est faite je comprendrais "qu'est-ce que t'as" ? ("Qu'est-ce t'ô?" avec disparition du second "que" et prononciation du "as" en "ô" qu'on entend dans certains accents.)

Le contexte se prête aussi aux *private jokes* donc ce n'est pas facile de proposer une réponse définitive.